# Running 'git status' from any folder shows status with a specific repo

Tags: git, git-status, .git-folder

When I type `git status` in any folder it lists the status of one of my git projects, compared to the current folder. Even when I am in another git project. Also, if I `cd` to `/root` folder and check there is no `.git` folder present and type in `git status` I will see the status of that folder against my git project.

Is there some default mapping in git, global config looks ok?

Comment: My guess is that you are inside some Git folder the entire time.  And maybe you have other projects inside that parent folder.  Do a search for `.git` and see what it turns up.

Comment: Do you happen to have `GIT_DIR` set in the environment?

Comment: Yes there is an env var GIT_DIR set to the offending repo

Answer (score 2):

When you have `GIT_DIR` set in the environment, but not also `GIT_WORK_TREE`, then you are operating Git outside its specifications.
Either:

- Remove `GIT_DIR` from the environment and let Git discover the `.git` directory itself,
- Or set `GIT_WORK_TREE` as well to point to the worktree corresponding to the `GIT_DIR`.

But, frankly, the latter is really not how one wants to operate Git during regular work. You should do the former.

Answer (score 1):

Well... it's in the comments, but for visibility:

This happens if you have a `GIT_DIR` environment variable pointing to a particular repository.  `GIT_DIR` overrides the normal directory-search rules for finding the `.git` folder and simply says "you're in a repo and the metadata is *here*".

Generally I would clear the `GET_DIR` variable, and only set it when needed.  I'm not sure what purpose you have it set for, and to the extent that purpose is still a thing, you may have to do some other stuff first to make sure it's set when it should be.  But I can say the only times I've ever used `GET_DIR` are in scripts (and then I make sure to clear it when the script's work is done) and I can't think of why you'd want it set all the time - for the reason you've just experienced.